# How to find which file contains a string from many files in a directory?

Tags: bash

For example, I have a directory that contains many files(say f1.dat, f2.dat ... , f100.dat). And I want to find out which file contains a string( say string "error"). How to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
grep -l "your_string" /your/dir/f*.dat
```

- `-l` list files that match the grep.
- `f*.dat` refers to all files which name is `f[something].dat`.

If you want to check it from all files in the directory, then this can be useful:

```
grep -l "your_string" /your/dir/
```

Comment: And if you have subfolders, go for `grep -rl "your_string" /your/dir/f*.dat`

Comment: Yes, sure. I did not add it as was not asked, but good point @Miquel.

Comment: I have a sub-question, in case `/your/dir/f*.dat` resolves to too many files, is not it better to use `--include=` flag? other wise, grep might want to error out saying too many arguments

Comment: Interesting question, @abasu. I am not familiar with `--include=` flag. We could also do it with `find` if we weren't looking for text inside. In this case, we can also create a stream like indicated in http://www.unix.com/302611311-post2.html . What do you think? Of course we are refering to directories with milions of files, which is extremely infrequent.

Comment: for `--include` man page says `Recurse in directories only searching file matching PATTERN.` So it seems an  easier way to avoid huge number of arguments. Also better than lengthier find command.

Comment: It looks fine, but in fact what we *do* is to search files matching PATTERN, so I cannot see the advantages of `--include` in this case.